# Apache Camel received Status 400 Bad Request from AWS VPC Endpont

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-vpc

I have a Java application which was built with Apache Camel. The application uses Apache Camel to construct an HTTP request to AWS VPC Endpoint.

When the Java application sends out an HTTP request, it receives HTTP Status Code 400 (Bad Request). The VPC Flow Log can be found with the traffic (correct source and destination IP addresses).

On the other hand, if we use curl command to send the same HTTP request, it turns back 200 OK.

What is a possible cause? Is there any configuration in Apache Camel to see what is the exact HTTP content or raw HTTP header/message sent out?

Comment: The URL configured inside Camel starts with http4 instead of typical http or https.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if Content-Type and other mandatory request headers are available at Exchange.in.headers. Just log in.headers within camel-simple tag. I think 400 happening because improper content-type or bad payload.

Comment: I tried to use curl to make a wrong content-type request but the response was 415 instead of 400.

Comment: Print the exception and sample payload you using here

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are sending headers that are not allowed by the API since Camel maps message headers automatically to HTTP headers.

Camel's camel-http4 component uses Apache HttpClient 4.x library and you can configure it to log raw http requests.

For instance with log4j you would add to properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```

Detailed logging options can be seen from here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html